# Injecting with roboguice on non-activity class

Tags: roboguice

Is there any way to inject custom bindings in a class that's not an activity (a class that doesn't extends RoboActivitiy? Because everytime I try to inject it, I get a NullPointerException when accessing it.

I've solved it getting the injector and doing it by myself... but that's something I don't feel comfortable with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class isn't itself created through injection, then obtaining the injector is the right (and only) way to do it.  That's how [`RoboActivity` (see `onCreate()`)](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/source/browse/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/activity/RoboActivity.java) does it in the first place.  Objects created through injection get their members Injected by the injector.